# GCE VM in Europe has US IP

Tags: ip, google-compute-engine

I have VM in GCE located in `europe-west1-b`

but when I traceroute VM's IP, it shows US:
[image]

..any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly which command did you use?

Trace Route command traces a route to a given IP address and your VM's external IP Address will be visible on your VM Instance homepage.

Comment: Well this website just sends random packets from different locations to the specified location.
The 21st hop was from USA that's why it's showing USA. It doesn't mean your instance is in the USA.

You can also cross-check this info by inserting your own personal IP address and see how much time it takes for different packets to reach you.